# Make Header Transparent on Twentyeleven theme

Tags: css, wordpress, header, wordpress-theming, customization

I have searched for an answer and haven't found anything that helps with my problem. I am using a child theme for twentyeleven and I am trying to make the header transparent so that it absorbs the page background. I have done the following in my child theme css.

```
/* =Header
----------------------------------------------- */

#branding {
border-top: 0px; 
padding-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
background: transparent !important;

} 
#site-title {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 5.9em 0 0 1.30em;
font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
#site-title a {
color: #000066;
font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: -5px;
font-size: 80px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#site-title a:hover,
#site-title a:focus,
#site-title a:active {
color: #000066;
font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
}
#site-description {
color: #000066;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
margin: 0 0px 1.35625em .8em;
text-align: center;
}
#branding img {
height: auto;
display: block;
width: 960px;

}
```

If you see anything I could add, change or remove. Or know of some other kind of trick to do in other parts of the css, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are div's behind it that are making it have a background, if you send me a link I will tell you exactly what to do but I am guessing that this is one of the culprits.

```
#page {
     background: #fff;
}
```

Make that

```
background:transparent;
```

Comment: Thank you, Zach! That worked. Now, I have a smaller problem but still just as elusive to me. There is now a bit of space between the navigation bar and the content, the sidebar is meeting the navigation bar just fine, it is only the content area. I am hoping you can help with that as well. If you have to have a link, is there a way to do that privately? Thanks again!

Comment: It will be tough to say but if I had the link I would go into chrome, right click and click inspect element. You may have to do that a few times to find the right thing. This is the thing that makes child themes insanely easier to build and you will get better at finding the right classes as you do it. Other than that I am not sure how to do a private message on here but if you figure it out feel free to send it over

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually figured it out, it was the entry-title variables.